# IE driver 4.0.0 stuck at This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver, microsoft-edge-extension, iedriverserver

I am using Internet Explorer driver 4.0.0(32bit) and selenium updated version 4.1.2when I run the code using Internet Explorer driver 4.0.0 it is stuck at This is the initial start page for the `WebDriver` server.
even though I check the setting in Internet Explorer:

1. All the protected mode is disabled
2. zoom setting is 100% for Internet Explorer and windows also
3. enchanted protected mode is off

but when I change the Internet Explorer driver to 3.1.4 it works fine. I also tried the Internet Explorer 4.0.0 for 64 but the same issue I am facing please help me.

```
public class EdgeTest {
    static RemoteWebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                "D:\\Automation\\Jar Details\\Drivers\\IEDriverServer_Win32_4.0.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        ieOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
        ieOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
        ieOptions.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
        ieOptions.setCapability("ignoreZoomSettings",true);
        System.out.println("this:"+ieOptions.getCapability("ignoreZoomSettings"));
         driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
        InternetExplorerDriverService.createDefaultService();
        driver.get("https://github.com/");
        WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        elem.sendKeys("gitu");

        elem.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        driver.quit();
```

> error: "Could not create a new remote session" this is an error
> getting

Comment: Same issue, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using selenium webdriver to automate Edge IE mode. I tried executing your code and I found this code to work fine (using IE driver 4.0.0 and Selenium 4.1.2).

But when executing code again before the code has not been executed complete, you get the same problem you describe (execute code twice at once). like this:

[image]

So I think when the IE driver may be occupied, you can try to open the task manager, end the related task (IE driver 32 bit), and then re-execute the code, I think this should be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for reply i am using cmd to close all the ie driver instance: taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe still its not working even only for ie to automate its stuck at this page only can just specify more.

Comment: Well, if this is the case, I'm afraid I can't think of any more ways to reproduce your issue. Becasuse when executing this code normally and it works fine in my case that used the same version. Maybe it might be because of other factors that affect compatibility, like OS, browser version? In my test, it's `windows 10 20H2 (OS biuld19042.1466)` and Edge Version `99.0.1150.46`. In short, if it is really not compatible with the current environment, I think you may have to use a lower version of the ie driver.

Comment: Ok I checked my browser version  also for edge it's 99.0 and I am using windows 10 Enterprise edition 2019 and for ie its 21H2 one thing  I just need to know if there is any extra jar file we need to use for example selenium.ie.jar 4.1.2 is available to work with it or it is ok to use selenium 4.1.2.jar file

Comment: I imported all relevant jar packages in the downloaded `selenium-java-4.1.2.zip` into the project（except chrome,firefox,opera）, so I think there should be no additional jar packages.