# IE Mode Edge driver stuck on 'This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server' when running in Elevated Mode (Admin Mode) [Selenium]

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, elevated-privileges

I am trying to run IE Mode on Edge. When the browser instance loads, it gets stuck on
`This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server`

Selenium Version - 4.18.1

I am using the below args. when initializing the browser.

```
admin_ie_options = webdriver.IeOptions()
admin_ie_options.add_argument('--ie-mode-test')
admin_ie_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
admin_ie_options.add_argument("--ignore-zoom-setting")
admin_ie_options.add_argument("--ignore-protected-mode-settings")
admin_ie_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
admin_ie_options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
admin_ie_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
admin_ie_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

d = webdriver.Ie(options=admin_ie_options)
d.maximize_window()
d.get(url) #Any URL
```

NOTE: It works fine if, I am not running the browser in Admin Mode, however my use case needs the browser to run in Admin Mode.

P.S:
I have tried the answers mentioned here, didn't work :(
[Selenium IE Webdriver stuck at "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server." with IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71562824/ie-driver-4-0-0-stuck-at-this-is-the-initial-start-page-for-the-webdriver-server)
[IE driver 4.0.0 stuck at This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71562824/ie-driver-4-0-0-stuck-at-this-is-the-initial-start-page-for-the-webdriver-server)

Edit1:

As @KendrickLi mentioned this is not possible to achieve currently. Refer -> (https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver/issues/87)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 2 lines

```
admin_ie_options.add_argument("--ignore-zoom-setting")
admin_ie_options.add_argument("--ignore-protected-mode-settings")
```

should be changed into

```
admin_ie_options.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True
admin_ie_options.ignore_zoom_level = True
```

because they are not the valid arguments for Microsoft Edge.

=================

If the issue still occurs, you can simply replace the initial start page with your URL:

```
admin_ie_options.initial_browser_url = 'url'
```

and `d.get(url)` can be removed in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I tried what you suggested
I am able to open the URL now, but the driver now gets on the URL, 
`d.get()` was not issue` , if I understand correctly and able to explain the same, the driver freezes after initiating the the browser instance.
E.g : the code snippet I provided, even before reaching d.get(), I am maximizing the browser instance, but it fails to do that. No error is thrown.
Let me know if any additional details are needed. Appreciate the support ! Thanks !

Comment: @subhamchomal I don't quite understand your current status, since you said your were able to open the URL now. What else is going wrong? `d.get(url)` and `admin_ie_options.initial_browser_url` function the same, so you may only choose one to avoid redundancy.

Comment: Sure @KendrickLi ,  The program freezes after we initiate the browser i.e.  after this line `d = webdriver.Ie(options=admin_ie_options)`  

Nothing after this line is executed. I am also not getting any error.

Comment: @subhamchomal Have you tried `admin_ie_options.initial_browser_url = 'url'`?

Comment: Updating my first comment .
Thanks for the reply ! I tried what you suggested I am able to open the URL now, but the driver now gets **stuck** on the URL , `d.get() was not issue` , if I understand correctly and able to explain the same, the driver freezes after initiating the the browser instance. E.g : the code snippet I provided, even before reaching d.get(), I am maximizing the browser instance, but it fails to do that. No error is thrown. Let me know if any additional details are needed. Appreciate the support ! Thanks !

Comment: Yes, I have tried the method you have suggested. 
The current behavior is that its **stuck on the URL** 
The previous behavior was that its **stuck on 'This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server'**
The error is constant, after `d = webdriver.Ie(options=admin_ie_options)` the driver is stuck i.e nothings executes post that (e.g `d.maximize_window()` `d.find_element(By.XPATH,Username).send_keys('xyz')` ).  `Note: this is only occuring when the browser in run in Elevated Mode`.  Apprreciate your support, Thanks !

Comment: @subhamchomal OK, I just realized that you are actually trying to pass Chromium arguments to IE, which is not valid. You need `'--no-sandbox'` to open Edge in Admin mode (in a stable manner), but you can't pass it via IE driver options. I think that's why it gets stuck. You know it is not recommended/supported to open Edge in Admin mode, though your project needs it. I'm afraid there's no solution to this issue. You will also find Edge Dev Team won't support such kind of scenario at https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver/issues/87

Comment: Understood! thanks for the link, I will try to look for a workaround, if I find something I will post it.